# read keyword in txt file, and print add text + keyword

Tags: python

I got many keywords in txt file to python using f = open().
And I want to add text before each keywords.

example,
(http://www.google.com/) + (abcdefg)
add text keywords imported

It have tried it, I can't result I want.

```
f = open("C:/abc/abc.txt", 'r')
data = f.read()
print("http://www.google.com/" + data)
f.close()
```

I tried it using "for".
But, I can't it.
Please let me know the solution.
many thanks.

Comment: And what output do you exactly expect? it is not very clear. Try to give a concise example of a file and what you want to add and how it will result

Comment: Please add for clarity, the full code. You write you used a for loop, then please add this code. If you get an error using for, please add the error as well. If the code works, but doesn't do what you expect, please add an example of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code has some flaws:

1. you only read the first line of the file, with `data = f.read()`. If you want to read all the lines from the file, use a `for`;
2. `data` is a `str`-type variable, which may have more than one word. Thus, you must split this line into words, using `data.split()`

To solve your problem, you need to read each line from the file, split the line into the words it has, then loop through the list with the words, add the desired text then the word itself.

The correct program is this:

```
f = open("C:/abc/abc.txt", 'r')
for data in f:
    words = data.split()
    for i in words:
        print("http://www.google.com/" + i)
f.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('text.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print("http://www.google.com/" + line)
```

Comment: Please describe your solution with text. Code only is not an answer.